# How to load .ml file with its corresponding .mli file in utop?

Tags: module, interface, ocaml, ocamlbuild, utop

Simply put, let us say I have an implementation file called `moduleExample.ml` and an interface file in the same directory called `moduleExample.mli`.

How could I load them together in such a way that the functions not listed in the interface `moduleExample.mli` are hidden from `moduleExample.ml`'s signature in `utop`? Additionally, how about type abstraction through the `moduleExample.mli` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper method to do that, or more generally load within a toplevel a whole project of several modules and interfaces, is to use a build system to compile all modules and link them within a toplevel.

Using [dune](https://github.com/ocaml/dune#dune---a-composable-build-system), you can do that by doing `dune utop directory` as described [here](https://github.com/ocaml/dune/blob/main/doc/usage.rst#launching-the-toplevel-repl). For exhaustiveness here's an architecture example:

**dune.ml**

```
(library
  (name dummy)
  (wrapped false)
)
```

**ex.ml**

```ml
type t = int
let of_int x = x
let to_string = string_of_int
let add = (+)
let print x = print_string (to_string x)
```

**ex.mli**

```
type t
val of_int : int -> t
val print : t -> unit
```

Loading all that into utop by doing `dune utop .` and then using the `#show` directive on the module `Ex`, gives:

```ml
utop # #show Ex;;
module Ex : sig type t val of_int : int -> t val print : t -> unit end
```